# is it possible use multi type in Class

Tags: java

I need to response a tree structure by json,
in my object,

```
{
MyClass 1:[{MyClass 11},{MyClass 12}],
MyClass 2:[{MyClass 21},{MyClass 22}],
MyClass 3:[{MyClass 31},{MyClass 32},
  {MyClass 33 :[{MyClass 331},{MyClass 332}]}
]
}
```

I used a `HashMap<MyClass, ArrayList<Object>>` to do this
and it worked, but when I trans to Json by Gson().toJson

it show `{MyClass Format: object Format}`

like this

```
{
"{Id=1, Name=HQS, parentId=0, level=1}":[
{
"_Id":5,
"_Name":"ADM",
"_originalName":"ADM",
"_parentId":1,
"_originalParentId":1,
"_setOriginalParentId":false,
"_level":2,
"_originalLevel":2,
"_setOriginalLevel":false,
"_columnBitmask":0,
"_cachedModel":false,
"_new":false
},
{
"{Id=2, Name=HQS, parentId=1, level=2}":[
{
"_Id":21,
"_Name":"ADMS",
"_originalName":"ADMS",
"_parentId":2,
"_originalParentId":2,
"_setOriginalParentId":false,
"_level":3,
"_originalLevel":3,
"_setOriginalLevel":false,
"_columnBitmask":0,
"_cachedModel":false,
"_new":false
}
]
}
]
}
```

I guess the point is Object, how could I fix it to show my class format?

Comment: just cast it to the type you need

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what you are expecting here. Your example does not seem to be valid JSON. The property key must always be a string. It cannot be a custom object.

If you put a custom object as key inside a map, the JSON serializer converts this key object to a string, using `toString()`. That's what you can see in your output.